# Find integer $x,y$ such that $y^{2}=41 x+3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find integer $x,y$ such that $y^{2}=41 x+3$

---

Through some algebraic manipulation, we can write it as $(y+1)(y-1) =41 x+2$, multiplying $y$ on both sides we get $(y-1)y(y+1)=(41x+2)y$. If $y$ is odd then we know $41x+2 \equiv (\bmod 4)$ $\rightarrow$ $x= 4k+2$ for some integer $k$. Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 4):

Note that 41 is a prime.We have $3^{\frac{41-1}{2}}=3^{20}\equiv (3^4)^5\equiv -1$(mod 41).

So 3 is a quadratic non residue modulo 41.So no such integer x and y exists

Comment: This is of course correct but I am not sure is at the OP's level. Maybe it would help to rework it in terms of little Fermat's theorem: if $y^2\equiv 3\pmod{41}$, then $41\not\mid y$ and $41$ prime $\implies$ $1\equiv y^{40}\equiv 3^{20}=(3^4)^5=81^{5}\equiv(-1)^5=-1\pmod{41}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Stinking Bishop thank you, it was easier to understand

Comment: @Euclid_Euler Have a look at [Legendre symbol](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreSymbol.html). In particular, formula 8: $\left(\frac{3}{41}\right)=3^\frac{41-1}{2}\pmod{41}$. See also [Quadratic residue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) for some background about the terminology used in this answer.